# Manipulate vanillaCalendar date with input date field

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can manipulate vanilla Calendar with input field?

If I select from input field date then it changes date in vanilla calendar.

Im using this vanilla calendar: https://vanilla-calendar.frontend.uvarov.tech

My code:

```js
/*

Manipulating should work without editing variable vanillacalendar.

*/
////////
var vanillacalendar = {
  month: document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-area="month"]')[0],
  next: document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-toggle="next"]')[0],
  previous: document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-toggle="previous"]')[0],
  label: document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-label="month"]')[0],
  activeDates: null,
  date: new Date(),
  todaysDate: new Date(),

  init: function () {
    this.date.setDate(1)
    this.createMonth()
    this.createListeners()
  },

  createListeners: function () {
    var _this = this
    this.next.addEventListener('click', function () {
      _this.clearCalendar()
      var nextMonth = _this.date.getMonth() + 1
      _this.date.setMonth(nextMonth)
      _this.createMonth()
    })
    // Clears the calendar and shows the previous month
    this.previous.addEventListener('click', function () {
      _this.clearCalendar()
      var prevMonth = _this.date.getMonth() - 1
      _this.date.setMonth(prevMonth)
      _this.createMonth()
    })
  },

  createDay: function (num, day, year) {
    var newDay = document.createElement('div')
    var dateEl = document.createElement('span')
    dateEl.innerHTML = num
    newDay.className = 'cal__date'
    newDay.setAttribute('data-calendar-date', this.date)

    if (num === 1) {
      var offset = ((day - 1) * 14.28)
      if (offset > 0) {
        newDay.style.marginLeft = offset + '%'
      }
    }

    if (this.date.getTime() <= this.todaysDate.getTime() - 1) {
      newDay.classList.add('cal__date--disabled')
    } else {
      newDay.classList.add('cal__date--active')
      newDay.setAttribute('data-calendar-status', 'active')
    }

    if (this.date.toString() === this.todaysDate.toString()) {
      newDay.classList.add('cal__date--today')
    }

    newDay.appendChild(dateEl)
    this.month.appendChild(newDay)
  },

  dateClicked: function () {
    var _this = this
    this.activeDates = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-status="active"]')
    for (var i = 0; i < this.activeDates.length; i++) {
      this.activeDates[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var picked = document.querySelectorAll('[data-calendar-label="picked"]')[0]
        picked.innerHTML = this.dataset.calendarDate
        _this.removeActiveClass()
        this.classList.add('cal__date--selected')
      })
    }
  },

  createMonth: function () {
    var currentMonth = this.date.getMonth()
    while (this.date.getMonth() === currentMonth) {
      this.createDay(this.date.getDate(), this.date.getDay(), this.date.getFullYear())
      this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1)
    }
    // while loop trips over and day is at 30/31, bring it back
    this.date.setDate(1)
    this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() - 1)

    this.label.innerHTML = this.monthsAsString(this.date.getMonth()) + ' ' + this.date.getFullYear()
    this.dateClicked()
  },

  monthsAsString: function (monthIndex) {
    return [
      'January',
      'Febuary',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'August',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December'
    ][monthIndex]
  },

  clearCalendar: function () {
    vanillacalendar.month.innerHTML = ''
  },

  removeActiveClass: function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.activeDates.length; i++) {
      this.activeDates[i].classList.remove('cal__date--selected')
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.logo {
  margin: 1.6rem auto;
  text-align: center;
}

a, a:visited {
  color: #0A9297;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1.6rem 0;
}

.container {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 1.6rem auto;
  max-width: 76rem;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.dtbtn {
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.cal__header button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  color: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cal button:active {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(10, 146, 151, 0.1)
}

.cal {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 42rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 22px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: solid 1px #e7e9ed;
}

.cal__header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.4rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.cal__header svg {
  fill: #0A9297;
}

.cal__header__label {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cal__week {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #E7E9ED;
}

.cal__week span {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  max-width: 14.28%;
  padding: 1.2rem 1.4rem;
  flex: 0 0 14.28%;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.cal__body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.cal__date {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 14.28%;
  flex: 0 0 14.28%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.2rem 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.cal__date--active:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cal__date--today {
  background-color: #0A9297;
  color: #fff;
}

.cal__date--selected {
  background-color: #E7E9ED;
  color: #333;
}

.cal__date--disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.cal__date--disabled:hover {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.demo-picked {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.demo-picked span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <svg class="logo" width="40" height="64" viewBox="0 0 80 128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>ice-cream</title><g fill="none"><path d="M77.877 47.673a6.515 6.515 0 0 1-1.912 4.619 6.515 6.515 0 0 1-4.618 1.912H8.653a6.53 6.53 0 0 1-4.618-11.149 6.515 6.515 0 0 1 4.618-1.912h3.918a6.53 6.53 0 0 1-4.618-11.149 6.515 6.515 0 0 1 4.619-1.912h3.918a6.53 6.53 0 0 1-4.618-11.15 6.515 6.515 0 0 1 4.618-1.911h2.613c0-7.213 5.848-13.062 13.06-13.062H60.9a13.02 13.02 0 0 1-3.828 9.234 13.02 13.02 0 0 1-9.234 3.828h15.674a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 4.618 11.148 6.515 6.515 0 0 1-4.619 1.913h3.919a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 4.618 11.149 6.515 6.515 0 0 1-4.618 1.912h3.918a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 6.53 6.53z" fill="#FFF"/><path d="M37.388 15.02h10.449a13.02 13.02 0 0 0 9.234-3.826 13.02 13.02 0 0 0 3.827-9.235H50.449a13.02 13.02 0 0 1-3.827 9.234 13.02 13.02 0 0 1-9.234 3.828zm33.959 26.123h-3.918a6.515 6.515 0 0 0 4.618-1.913 6.53 6.53 0 0 0-4.618-11.149h-3.918a6.515 6.515 0 0 0 4.618-1.912 6.53 6.53 0 0 0-4.618-11.149H53.062a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 4.618 11.15 6.515 6.515 0 0 1-4.618 1.911h3.918a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 4.618 11.15 6.515 6.515 0 0 1-4.618 1.912h3.918a6.53 6.53 0 0 1 4.618 11.149 6.515 6.515 0 0 1-4.618 1.912h10.449a6.515 6.515 0 0 0 4.618-1.912 6.53 6.53 0 0 0-4.618-11.149z" fill="#EBE5DD"/><path fill="#FFDA44" d="M63.249 77.71425L53.06125 126.04075 26.93875 126.04075 16.751 77.71425"/><path d="M16.751 77.714l1.101 5.225h31.12c3.319 0 5.796 3.054 5.112 6.302l-7.758 36.8h6.736l10.187-48.327H16.751z" fill="#EEBF00"/><path fill="#FFDA44" d="M67.242 77.71425L12.758 77.71425 7.347 54.204 72.653 54.204z"/><path d="M66.226 54.204L62.95 68.437a5.225 5.225 0 0 1-5.09 4.053H11.555l1.202 5.224h54.484l5.41-23.51h-6.426z" fill="#EEBF00"/><path d="M79.837 47.673c0-3.667-2.338-6.799-5.603-7.983a8.427 8.427 0 0 0 1.684-5.078c0-3.668-2.338-6.799-5.602-7.983A8.427 8.427 0 0 0 72 21.55c0-4.681-3.809-8.49-8.49-8.49h-5.56A14.921 14.921 0 0 0 62.857 1.96V0H32.163C24.546 0 18.24 5.702 17.275 13.061h-.785c-2.269 0-4.401.883-6.004 2.486A8.436 8.436 0 0 0 8 21.551c0 1.9.627 3.656 1.686 5.072a8.459 8.459 0 0 0-3.118 1.985 8.434 8.434 0 0 0-2.486 6.004c0 1.9.627 3.656 1.686 5.072A8.456 8.456 0 0 0 2.65 41.67a8.433 8.433 0 0 0-2.486 6.003c0 3.63 2.288 6.732 5.498 7.944l5.535 24.057h3.965L25.349 128h29.302l10.187-48.326h3.965l5.534-24.052a8.461 8.461 0 0 0 3.013-1.945 8.434 8.434 0 0 0 2.487-6.004zm-70.029 8.49h6.742l3.006 19.592h-5.24L9.809 56.163zm41.388 19.592L52.7 56.163h6.787l-3.005 19.592h-5.285zm-3.93 0H41.96V56.163h6.81l-1.503 19.592zm-9.225 0h-5.307L31.23 56.163h6.81v19.592zM27.3 56.163l1.503 19.592h-5.285l-3.005-19.592H27.3zm24.171 67.919H28.528l-9.361-44.408h41.667l-9.362 44.408zm14.211-48.327h-5.238l3.005-19.592h6.742l-4.508 19.592zm8.897-24.848a4.542 4.542 0 0 1-3.233 1.338H8.653a4.577 4.577 0 0 1-4.572-4.572c0-1.221.476-2.37 1.339-3.233a4.542 4.542 0 0 1 3.233-1.338h20.898v-3.918h-16.98A4.577 4.577 0 0 1 8 34.612c0-1.222.475-2.37 1.338-3.233a4.542 4.542 0 0 1 3.234-1.338H40v-3.919H16.49a4.577 4.577 0 0 1-4.572-4.571c0-1.222.476-2.37 1.339-3.233a4.541 4.541 0 0 1 3.233-1.338h7.837V13.06h-3.09c.93-5.19 5.474-9.143 10.926-9.143h26.604a11.025 11.025 0 0 1-3.081 5.89 11.03 11.03 0 0 1-7.85 3.253H37.389v3.919H63.51c2.52 0 4.572 2.05 4.572 4.571 0 1.222-.475 2.37-1.338 3.233a4.542 4.542 0 0 1-3.234 1.338H53.061v3.919h14.367c2.521 0 4.572 2.05 4.572 4.571 0 1.222-.475 2.37-1.338 3.233a4.542 4.542 0 0 1-3.234 1.339H42.612v3.918h28.735c2.52 0 4.572 2.05 4.572 4.572 0 1.221-.476 2.37-1.339 3.233z" fill="#000"/></g></svg>

        <h1>Date input field should change vanilla calendar date</h1>
    <input type="date" class="dtbtn">
        <div class="cal">
            <div class="cal__header">
                <button class="btn btn-action btn-link btn-lg" data-calendar-toggle="previous"><svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path></svg></button>
                <div class="cal__header__label" data-calendar-label="month">
                    March 2017
                </div><button class="btn btn-action btn-link btn-lg" data-calendar-toggle="next"> <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path></svg></button>
            </div>
            <div class="cal__week">
                <span>Mon</span> <span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span> <span>Thu</span> <span>Fri</span> <span>Sat</span> <span>Sun</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cal__body" data-calendar-area="month"></div>
        </div>

        <p class="demo-picked">
            Date picked: <span data-calendar-label="picked"></span>
        </p>

        <footer>
            <a href="https://github.com/chrisssycollins">@chrisssycollins</a> | <a href="https://github.com/chrisssycollins/vanilla-calendar">View on GitHub</a>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="vanillacalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
          vanillacalendar.init();
        })
    </script>
```

When pick date with input field it should change date in vanilla calendar.
I have plugin what uses vanilla calendar and I want manipulate it with datepicker.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).